# Create Relationship Between Successive Elements in List

Tags: list, neo4j, cypher

I need to be able to create a sequence of events with a relationship between each to describe the succession of events. I know that I can create an ordered list of their node IDs in timestamp order i.e.

```
MATCH (ch:Checkin)
WITH ch
ORDER BY ch.timestamp ASC
WITH collect(id(ch)) AS checkins
```

what I'm after is the best way to use this list of node ids to create relationships between each in succession i.e.

Checkin_0 <-FOLLOWS- Checkin_1 <-FOLLOWS- Checkin_2 and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`RANGE`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-range) and [`UNWIND`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/#unwind-unwind-a-list) to enumerate the checkins in the loop:

```
MATCH (ch:Checkin)
WITH ch ORDER BY ch.timestamp ASC
WITH COLLECT(ch) AS checkins
UNWIND RANGE(1, size(checkins)-1) AS i
WITH checkins[i-1] AS prev,
     checkins[i] AS next
MERGE (prev)<-[f:FOLLOWS]-(next)
RETURN prev, f, next
```

Comment: Thanks. Something isn't quite right. If I try to list checkins e.g. `MATCH (ch:Checkin) RETURN ch LIMIT 5` it never appears to complete the query. Nor does `size((:Checkin)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Checkin))`. Expanding an old query by selecting a Checkin node does show the desired sequence.

Comment: My query is absolutely correct. By the way, how much data do you have in sequence? What if you return `COUNT (f)` instead `prev, f, next`?

Comment: It's a small dataset - there are only 498 Checkins. In fact can't get any new query to complete - have stopped + restarted to no avail.

Comment: It's repeatable on recreating the dataset and it's browser-dependent (Safari). After executing the query Safari won't return the results of any queries until it is quit + restarted. Firefox will. Question answered. Different problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can also take a look at installing and using [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). There's a procedure called `apoc.nodes.link()` that takes a collection and a relationship type string and creates those relationships between each of the nodes in sequence.

```
MATCH (ch:Checkin)
WITH ch
ORDER BY ch.timestamp DESC
WITH collect(ch) AS checkins
CALL apoc.nodes.link(checkins, 'FOLLOWS')
RETURN checkins
```

Comment: Yes. Works. Linked set suffers same new problem - cannot return (:Checkin)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:Checkin) and unable to query anything afterwards (Firefox + Safari).